# An example of a total order (that is NOT a well-order) of the Natural numbers

Tags: relations, natural-numbers

I need an example of a total ordering of the Natural numbers, that is not a well-ordering. So the classic "less than or equal to" doesn't work in this case since it is well-ordered.

I've been wracking my brain for hours but I can't just conjure up a relation. Is there a relatively simple one I'm forgetting?

Comment: A personal favorite: [Sharkovskii's order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sharkovskii%27s_theorem).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about:$$\ldots,7,5,3,1,0,2,4,6,\ldots$$

Or even simpler, just turn $\Bbb N$ around!

**Added:** To make that last idea more precise, define a relation $\preceq$ on $\Bbb N$ by $m\preceq n$ if and only if $n\le m$. Then check that $\preceq$ is a linear order on $\Bbb N$ that is not a well-order. (The last is clear, since for any $n\in\Bbb N$, $n+1\preceq n$, and therefore $\Bbb N$ has no $\preceq$-least element.)

Comment: Turning the naturals around sounds like an idea... but how do you define that? Maybe my idea of orderings is a too formal...

Comment: @Auron: I’ve added it to my answer, though I’ve left a little checking for you.

Comment: Ah :) Thank you! I think I get the idea. It's essentially reversing it so that "have no least element" now translates to "have no greatest element", which is true of the naturals. Thank you for the help!

Comment: @Auron: That’s exactly right. You’re welcome!

Answer (score 3):

What about reverse order? i.e. $n\prec m$ if $n>m$.

Comment: I'm guessing this is the same idea as Brians post below/above? Question though - that particular relation would need to be n "greater than or equal to", wouldn't it? Surely if it was just "greater than", then it would fail to be reflexive and therefore not even partially ordered?